# issue with mod-mono on centos 7

Tags: apache-2.4, asp.net, mono

I am new to Linux hosting. We have some ASP.NET sites hosted on Windows IIS. We are now going to migrate those site to Apache Webserver. After study, I found we can use "mod-mono" for this purpose. I have installed Apache & mod-mono for this purpose on our new CENTOS 7 webserver.
Output of **"mono-V"** -

```
Mono JIT compiler version 5.14.0.176 (tarball Fri Aug  3 08:39:03 UTC
2018) Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and
Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        Interpreter:   yes
        LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-/)
        GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

Output of **"httpd -v"** -

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server built:   Jun 27 2018 13:48:59
```

I have also added following lines to **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file -

```
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf 
Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_mono.conf

LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so

<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html Default.aspx </IfModule>

AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

My Apache server is able to host & show normal HTML page. But when trying to run index.aspx page, it is showing

> 503 Service unavailable

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Check your Apache error log.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start the mod-mono-server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please let me know how to start that?

Comment: What is the name of your mono application?  You can start it like "mono Server.exe".   Allthough https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/ says that mod_mono should start the server all by itself.  You did install the server?